# Apache randomly crashing

Tags: apache-2.4, memory-usage

so apparently apache has been intermittently crashing overnight and the apache error log has shown nothing that is suspicious. I would have to reboot my server each time to get apache running again. The server is still connectable, just apache seems to have disappeared on me.

When I checked messages log, I noticed a ton of messages like:

```
Apr 29 14:46:08 test_web kernel: *BAD*gran_size: 8M     chunk_size: 32M     num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: -18M
Apr 29 14:46:08 test_web kernel: *BAD*gran_size: 8M     chunk_size: 64M     num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: -18M
Apr 29 14:46:08 test_web kernel: *BAD*gran_size: 8M     chunk_size: 128M    num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: -10M
Apr 29 14:46:08 test_web kernel: *BAD*gran_size: 8M     chunk_size: 256M    num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: -10M
Apr 29 14:46:08 test_web kernel: *BAD*gran_size: 8M     chunk_size: 512M    num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: -10M
Apr 29 14:46:08 test_web kernel: *BAD*gran_size: 8M     chunk_size: 1G  num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: -506M
Apr 29 14:46:08 test_web kernel: *BAD*gran_size: 8M     chunk_size: 2G  num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: -1530M
```

This looks like a hardware issue? What can I do?

Comment: I suggest you to run memtest in your server (http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm) as far as it seems you have some trouble with your RAM.

Comment: @alphamikevictor I sent a support ticket to my hosting provider and they suspected the RAM was faulty. They replaced it but when I checked kernel messages again I still see the *BAD*gran_size messages. They also update my BIOS so I am at a stump right now.

Comment: Take a look to this https://velenux.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/badgran_size-in-dmesg/ perhaps can help

Comment: @alphamikevictor Thanks, my hosting provider suggested something similar with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset rd.auto=1 crashkernel=auto enable_mtrr_cleanup mtrr_spar_reg_nr=1 mtrr_gran-size=4M mtrr_chunk_size=128M"`, I just rebooted and saw the same *BAD*gran_size. Wondering if I needed to update-grub for it to take effect? I am running on CentOS 7 and modified /etc/default/grub file.